# I'm getting an error while trying to link python with mysql

Tags: python, mysql, typeerror, pymysql

```
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 5 were given
```

this was the error and I will share the script below:

```
import pymysql
print('---DATABASE CONNECTION SAMPLE---')
x=pymysql.connect('localhost','root','sha@123','avodha')
cr=x.cursor()

cr.execute('create table student(name char(50),age int)')

x.close()
```

Comment: `connect` accepts keyword arguments only

Answer (score 1):

`connect` doesn't take positional arguments, it takes keyword arguments:

```py
x = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                    user='user',
                    password='passwd',
                    database='avodha')
```

Comment: I tried this and it shows invalid syntax

Comment: Thank you the syntax error was a mistake from my side and I got it working